# $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m} $ is a linear mapping. What is its derivative?

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations, partial-derivative

Let's assume that $$ f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m} $$ is a linear mapping. What is its derivative?

I know what a linear mapping is. 
And I also know that the derivative $ Df(x_{0}) $ of $ f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) = (f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{m}) $ at a point $x_{0}$ is a $m\times n$ matrix with values $t_{ij}=\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}$ at this point.

What should I WRITE to solve this problem? What is a right answer?

Comment: There are several derivatives in dimension greater than $1$. Do you mean derivative or differential?

Comment: Wrong. Definition of derivative is different, it's a linear map $A$, s.t. the limit of $h$ going to 0 of $1/||h|| (f(x+h) - f(x) - Ah)$ is zero. Only sometimes it happens to coincide with your definition. More generalny, od derivative exists, then it has the form you mentioned. But sometimes all partial derivatives exist, but derivative doesn't.

Comment: @Gibbs The exercise says "derivative"

Comment: @enedil So what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: @enedil  Why is OP wrong?  As the derivative is a linear mapping it certainly takes that form in the standard basis (when the derivatives exists: if it doesn't then it's a moot point).

Comment: @Dr.Mathematics  Do you mean "linear" in the sense of linear algebra?  Or do you mean linear as in $f(\mathbf{x} ) = A\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}$?  (The $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}$ case would be the linear algebra meaning.)

Comment: @enedil Right, I think his bone to pick was the fact that the existence of all those partials doesn't imply differentiability.

Comment: @Dr.Mathematics Ok, but that is not precise. You should try to understand a bit more from the context. I am inclined to think you want the differential.

Comment: @Randall well, I read this as a definition of derivative, not necessarily in this context. Of course, partial derivatives of linear functions are linear functions and linear functions are continuous, so in fact this is true that the derivative takes this form. But here, if we talk about general definition, I consider it wrong. Moreover, the definition I suggested is more helpful in this task.

Comment: Perhaps you should assume the derivative exists at $0$, call it $f'(0)$ if you like, and then prove the derivative exists everywhere and can be written in terms of $f'(0)$.

Comment: @enedil  Your definition is the "right" one, but it also makes my point.  It doesn't matter if $f$ is linear or not.  If it exists, $D_{x_0}f$ is a linear map, so it **is** a matrix, and its entries are in fact given by partial derivatives.

Comment: @Randall ok, if it's framed this way, it's indeed correct. Pardon for my confusion

Comment: @enedil To be fair, OP should directly apply your definition and be done with the whole problem.